# It's probably because you joined several Datasets together, error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've below code snippet

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Test").getOrCreate()

    val seq = Seq("one", "two")

    val tableA = Seq((100, "bob", 200, "abc"),(300, "pop", 400, "xyz"))

    val schema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("nameId", IntegerType, false),
      StructField("namePip", StringType, false),
      StructField("locId", IntegerType, false),
      StructField("locPip", StringType, false),
    ))

    val rowData = tableA.map(d => Row(d._1,d._2,d._3,d._4))
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rowData)
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    df.show()


    val tableB = Seq((100,200),(300, 400))

    val schemaB = StructType(Array(
      StructField("nId", IntegerType, false),
      StructField("locId", IntegerType, false)
    ))

    val rowDataB = tableB.map(d => Row(d._1,d._2))
    val rddB = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rowDataB)
    val dfB = spark.createDataFrame(rddB, schemaB)
    dfB.show()


    val op = seq.foldLeft(df)((ip,seqElement) => {

      ip.join(dfB,
        ip("nameId") === dfB("nId"), "inner"
      ).drop()
    })

    op.show()
```

Not able to get, why I'm getting below error

```
Column nId#62 are ambiguous. It's probably because you joined several Datasets together, and some of these Datasets are the same. This column points to one of the Datasets but Spark is unable to figure out which one. Please alias the Datasets with different names via `Dataset.as` before joining them, and specify the column using qualified name
```

After joining, I'm dropping `nId` too, so that in next join it dont become ambiguous. Because If I run the foldLeft only for element in `seq`, it works. I want it should work for all iterations in `seq`

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong, and how it can be fixed ?

Thanks

Comment: is there a parameter (`nId`) missing inside of `drop()`?

Answer (score 0):

Aliases can be assigned to dataframes for join:

```
  ip.alias("ip")
    .join(dfB.alias("b"),
      $"ip.nameId" === $"b.nId", "inner")
```